# Does RPi 2 like android USB wifi tethering?

Tags: usb, wifi

After connecting my Xperia Z1 with 4.4.3 Android the red and green Pi diode disappearing (or maybe lighting very low ?). Pi works well, see that the phone is connected but the wifi tethering by USB doesn't work for Pi. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You've said "tethering doesn't work".  What do you mean?  How have you tried to access the phone?

Comment: What do you mean "wifi tethering by USB" - are you tethering over wifi or over USB? is the Pi plugged into the phone's USB port? how does it see it connected?

Comment: Sorry, the tethering to my Pi doesn't work. Normally the tethering works nice on PC/Mac.

Comment: again, WHICH tethering, wifi OR usb?

Comment: Wifi thought USB cable (internet sharing - the phone is connected to Wifi, and share's the connection though the USB cable)